# Setting relative path to file in SpringBoot application.properties not working

Tags: java, spring, ssl

I wish to set in application.properties the relative path to a file (a truststore.jks file in resources folder) because I don't want to do it directly in the code with :

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("truststore.jks").getPath();
```

So, I tried to do it like this :

```
    @Value("${truststore.path}")
    private String truststorePath;


    truststore.path=classpath:truststore.jks
```

However, this doesn't work, the app doesn't seem to find the file. What does work is specifying the absolute path, like this :

```
truststore.path=C://Users//X//Documents//Project//my-project//src//main//resources//keystore.jks
```

How can I make it work with a relative path ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried `truststore.path=truststore.jks`?

Comment: @talex i did try that, but still the same problem not finding the file ...

Comment: How do you use `truststorePath`?

Comment: @talex i actually use it as a parameter in a method that comes from a JAR that i do not own and that method then uses the parameter as such : InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(truststorePath)); It then sends the result to a TrustManager.

Comment: Then you can't use classpath resources. `File` doesn't support them.

Comment: @talex oh thanks, i did not know that. since i cannot change the JAR method that uses File, do you know how i can specify a relative path for a file in application.properties (without "classpath:" then), or is it not possible ? i really don't want to put an absolute path there